# Swipe screen Xiaomi Poco 5X remotely

Tags: android, adb, poco, xiaomi

Setup:

- Xiaomi Poco 5X dev phone with remote access `adb` to it.
- Vyzor installed however can only view screen because Xiaomi requires additional debugging flags be enabled

Problem:
The phone only requires a swipe to unlock.
I manage to turn on the screen with :

```
adb -s XXXXX shell svc power stayon true
```

However, when trying to swipe :

```
adb -s XXXXX shell "input touchscreen swipe 126 459 913 472"
Exception occurred while executing 'touchscreen':
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
        at com.android.server.input.InputManagerService.injectInputEventInternal(InputManagerService.java:914)
        at com.android.server.input.InputManagerService.injectInputEvent(InputManagerService.java:866)
        at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:1091)
        at com.android.server.input.InputShellCommand.injectMotionEvent(InputShellCommand.java:138)
        at com.android.server.input.InputShellCommand.sendSwipe(InputShellCommand.java:370)
        at com.android.server.input.InputShellCommand.runSwipe(InputShellCommand.java:354)
        at com.android.server.input.InputShellCommand.onCommand(InputShellCommand.java:194)
        at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
        at com.android.server.input.InputManagerService.onShellCommand(InputManagerService.java:3551)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:956)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:840)
        at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub.onTransact(IInputManager.java:1144)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1149)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't enable USB debugging (Security Settings) in the developer options because I hadn't signed in to Xiaomi (I don't have an account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this [swipe](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/33c6f40cbbd5b4c45002a98fbb3405098c10d5ac/examples/helper/swipe) example from [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

helper = ViewClient.view_client_helper()


helper.ui_device.swipe(segments=[(300, 300), (600, 1200), (600, 300), (300, 300)], segment_steps=50)
```

of course you need to adapt the coordinates.

Here is the result from previous command when Keep is the top activity (so we can actually see it drawing)

[image]